# java access class's variable in thread and use outside thread

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, thread-safety

I've a GUI Class Named as `NewFrame.java` and another one is `Client.java`. in Client.java, the NewFrame's object is made inside a thread. ex,

```
public class ClientA {

NewJFrame gui;
int x ;

public void go() {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gui  = new NewJFrame();
                gui.setVisible(true);
                x = 10;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(x); // does not print 10 but it prints 0

        gui.setTextboxvalue("value changed !!!"); 

        // can'se pass value to the function, with this error occurs as,
        // "java.lang.NullPointerException" at here.

      }
}
```

here two problems occuring,
there is the setter method in NewFrame class named `setTextboxValue` but calling this as shown above the error occurs "java.lang.NullPointerException".

another problem is : why i can't set the variable `x` inside that thread, setting this inside thread, the outside printing the variable `x`'s value which is 10 is not printing there instead it prints `0`

Comment: *"i've a gui class called.."*  Do you have a shift key?  That should be *"I've a GUI class called.."*.  Please show more effort in future.

Comment: Question is Updated as per your Desire !!!

Answer (score 2):

`EventQueue.invokeLater` invokes its methods on a separate thread, which is fired off asynchronously on the event dispatch thread after all the other tasks on the event dispatch thread have finished.  In other words, that code inside the run() method is likely going to be executed after your method finishes.  Therefore, the `gui` variable is still going to be null, resulting in a `NullPointerException` when you call `gui.setTextboxvalue`; and x is still going to be 0 when you print out the value.

Comment: so what is the solution to access it ?

Comment: You can either create the NewJFrame instance in your main thread, or you can do the other work in the event dispatch thread after the NewJFrame instance has been initialized.

Comment: the code under `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` is autogenerated with netbeans and i think its not good to initialize the gui class out of the `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` ..

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Use a second EventQueue.invokeLater to wrap around setTextboxvalue

Comment: @EricGalluzzo See [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for reasons why it's a bad idea to initialise the UI outside of the EDT

Comment: is it safe to declare `gui  = new NewJFrame();` outside the thread ? eg. before the thread ?